# Has J.J.Jameson ever found out that Peter Parker is Spider-Man?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

I haven't read the comics, only seen some Spider-Man movies and The Animated Series, so I wonder if J.J.Jameson has ever found out that Peter Parker is Spider-Man?

Comment: He finds out Peter's identity on an almost weekly basis in the comics

Comment: And then there are time travel/change issue that really muddy the waters...

Comment: @K-H-W - Not to mention the time that JJ was Spider-Man's dad; https://www.amazon.com/What-Jonah-Jameson-Adopted-Spider-Man/dp/B002VD34KM

Comment: @Valorum Issue#82? No wonder Marvel were brave enough to announce the What If at Comic-con this year. they have a ton of story-lines ready

Comment: Is your question specifically about the comics?

Comment: Saw this on the Hot Network Questions list. Thanks for spoiling it: now I know Peter Parker is Spider-Man. `:-)`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### In the comics, Peter once willingly revealed his identity to JJJ.

**TL; DR.** 
In ***Peter Parker The Spectacular Spider-Man Issue # 6***, Spider-Man agrees for a dinner/interview with J. Jonah Jameson. Long story short, Peter reveals his identity to JJJ just to make him understand that not all masked people around are bad people (NOTE: JJJ's wife was killed by a masked criminal; it's covered in detail in this issue)

[image]
<sub>*Peter Parker The Spectacular Spider-Man Issue # 6*</sub>

You could watch the summary of this issue [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOPae2NCbl4)

---

### The second instance is when he goes public!

In Marvel’s 2006 event storyline, "Civil War" by Mark Millar and drawn by Steve McNiven, Peter gave up his identity to the world. The superhero registration act forced the heroes to reveal their identity and Peter does the same; goes public with his identity. JJJ in fact faints after watching this.

[image]
<sub>*Civil War Issue #2 (2006)*</sub>

---

Talking about the MCU version of Spider-Man, in *Spider-Man: Far From Home*,

> his identity was also revealed in the post-credits scene. JJJ goes live with the breaking news telling the whole world about Spidey's secret identity which was [presumably] shared/sent to him by Mysterio before his death.

Comment: And once again JK Simmons was PERFECT for that role :)....

Comment: Notably, the Peter Parker: The Spectacular Spider-Man #6 issue is from Volume 3, (2017), which would put it chronologically between Civil War #2 and the third answer.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan I was so happy to see them transition him into the MCU.

Answer (score 25):

In issue 12 from 1964, a virus leaves Peter too weak to fight Doc Ock but he tries anyway, and gets beat. Ock then removes Peter's mask in front of everyone, including JJJ:

[image: Doc Ock unmasks Spider-Man]

However, since Peter is too weak to fight or use his powers, nobody believes that he's actually Spider-Man, rather that Peter simply dressed up as him.

Comment: This is a great find. I guess this inspired the unmasking of Spider-Man in the animated series. where the sinister-six kidnap Aunt May and force Peter to bring them Spider-Man and around the same time peter has lost his powers..

Comment: I don't remember Spider-Man ever fighting Elton John.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimate Jameson also finds out about Ultimate Spider-Man, right before he is seemingly killed by Ultimate Chameleon on Earth 1610. Chameleon captures both Jameson and Peter and while in captivity together Jameson figures it out, right before Chameleon shoots him in the head.

https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Ultimate_Comics_Spider-Man_Vol_1_14